# Rails Gem “Axlsx” - Adding Image Fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

> SO.Windows 10

> ruby : 2.6.6

> rails : 6.0.3.2

> axlsx : 2.0.1

this is my code.

```
img = File.expand_path(Rails.root + "app/javascript/img/logo-finky.png", __FILE__)
    sheet.add_image(:image_src => img, :noSelect => true, :noMove => true, end_at: true, :hyperlink => "https://www.finky.la/") do |image|
      image.width = 64
      image.height = 64
      image.hyperlink.tooltip = "Finky"
    end
```

[image]

> this is the error when opening the file
>
> If I press yes then it shows the information

[image]

> it only happens when I add an image

Comment: `axlsx` was handed over to the community 8 years ago and now goes by `caxlsx`. "2.0.1" was the last build of `axlsx` before this transition. Have you considered switching to `caxlsx` and upgrading your gem version? Current stable is [3.1.0](https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx/tree/v3.1.0).

Comment: Indeed there was a pull request that addressed image loading in the last year. You will probably have better luck with the latest caxlsx, which also addresses the recent mime security issues. https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx